# Xpath expression for considering text nodes in document.evaluate method

Tags: javascript, xpath

If I have XMl node as below

```
<div> 
       Test
       <div> Test </div>
       <div> Test </div>
</div>
```

And if I have Javascript code as below, it is not considering first text node. Can you please help me on what is the underlying issue with below javascript code?

```
         var xpath = "*//text()";                        
        var snapshot = document.evaluate(xpath, rootNode, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

Comment: What makes you think there is an issue? What results are you expecting and what results are you getting?

Comment: Agree with @MichaelKay ,  Please share Error which you are getting

Comment: There is no error but what I am expecting is I need to get 3 results but I am getting only 2 results from snapshot 2nd and 3rd. And 1st one is getting ignored.  I need all 3 values from above example.